# How to submit a form when tab is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to submit a form, when a tab is clicked.  This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Submit a Form on Tab Click</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            </style>

            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#Main" ).tabs();
                 });
            </script>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Tab1').click(function(){
            $('#Form_1').submit();
            });

</script> 

        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Main">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tab5">Tab5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tab6">Tab6</a></li>
           </ul> 

           <form id="Form_1" action="Tab_Click_v00.html" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="Nb_var99" value="1">
           </form>

            <div id="Tab1">
                <p>Tab1</p> 
            </div>
            <div id="Tab2">
                <p>Tab2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Tab3">
                <p>Tab3</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Tab4">
                <p>Tab4</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Tab5">
                <p>Tab5</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Tab6">
                <p>Tab6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Each tab will submit a different form. I hope this helps to identify what I am trying to 
achieve.  I am new to all this so please be specific.

Thank you.

Comment: where is form in your markup ?

Comment: one hesitation would be that most people tab through different elements on a form and may not be aware it will submit

Comment: Is it the same form for every tab click or a different form depending on the tab clicked?

Comment: Hi Tushar, that's all I have. I don't know how to do the rest. I don't know where form is suppose to be or how to create it. Sorry!

Comment: Hi Jon, its Ok that people will not know something is happening.  In fact, I don't want people to know that I am initiating a variable behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I will be initiating a variable with a different value, but I must submit a form like so:  <form method="post" action="test.html" name="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="Nb_var02" value="hello"> 
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jQuery:

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Tv9m/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#Main" ).tabs();

    $('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function() {
        var tabId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('Tab clicked: ' + tabId );

        if (tabId == 'ui-id-1') {
            $('#LoginForm').submit();
        }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-2') {
            $('#form2').submit();
        }else if (tabId == 'ui-id-3') {
            $('#form3').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

jQueryUI tabs all have IDs beginning with `ui-id-#`, where # is the tab number (for example, `ui-id-3`.

The selector `$('[id^=ui-id-]')` means: *For any element whose ID attribute begins with `ui-id-`, trap the click event and do this...*

Note that the `<form>` tag must have an ID attribute, as specified in the above code. For example, for the form on Tab 3:

```
<form id="form3" action="whatever.php" method="POST">
```

---

Suppose each tab has a form on it and, for example, the forms all have IDs that are sequentially numbered according to the tab they are on, such as Form-1, Form-2, Form-5, etc. Then you could use the line `var tabId = $(this).attr('id')` to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#Main" ).tabs();

    $('[id^=ui-id-]').click(function() {
        var tabId = $(this).attr('id'); //ui-id-4
        var tabNum = tabId.split('-')[2]; //4
        $('#Form-' + tabNum).submit();
    });
});
```

For example, suppose the tab's ID is `ui-id-4`, then you would want to give the `<form>` for tab 4 an ID: `<form id="Form-4">`.  The above code would then submit that form when the tab was clicked.

---

Note that the above code expects that your form tags will have an ID, such as:

```
<form id="myFormId" action="somepage.php" method="POST" >
```

Comment: Ok maybe I am doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I did: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Tab1').click(function(){
$('#Form_1').submit();
});
$('#Tab2').click(function(){
$('#form2').submit();
});
$('#Tab3').click(function(){
$('#form3').submit();
});
});
</script>

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested in my answer? That did not require you to make any changes to your HTML. However, the way you coded it above requires that you add an ID to each anchor `<a>` tag, and *be careful of the capitalization!* Tag != tag

Comment: @NeilPorven I modified my example to respond to your comment above. See revised code in first example. Read my comments (in the post) carefully. You should be fine with that -- you *do* understand about setting the ID attribute in the form tags, and matching that to what tab was clicked, yes?

Comment: Ok, I tried your code, it works! Thank youuuuuuuu.  Is there a way from stopping the web-site to automatically go back to tab1?

Comment: @NeilPorven Thanks for the accept. Please upvote any answers you found helpful (can do both if desired). And Yes, there is a way to stop that -- you must use AJAX. If you want further help with that aspect, please post as another question (just mod this question to (1) update your code a bit, and (2) ask how to prevent website from going back to Tab 1.  I'll keep a close eye on new questions.

Comment: @NeilPorven For your new question: do all forms POST to the same PHP page, or please specify which PHP page each form goes to (or at least two of them so we can create a meaningful example). Also, post a note under this one (if you would) if/when you are ready to post the new question.

Comment: You were missing the <script type="text/javascript"> attribute, also you should check the id's of each tab you wanna bind the click to and each form you want to submit. I have updated the jsfiddle in case you still wanna give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form will have an id of 'myform', you can put a click event listener on the tabs.

Add a class to your tabs `class='tab'`

```
$('.tab').on('click', function(){
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The tabs widget has some events you can use.  For example, when a tab is activated, you can have a handler for [the `activate` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate).  You can use standard jQuery event handling, and specify the `tabsactivate` event.  Something like this:

```
$('#Main').on('tabsactivate', function (event, ui) {
    // your logic here
    $('#someForm').submit();
});
```

You can inspect the `ui` argument passed to that event handler for information about the tab.  For example, the specific tab being moved from/to.  Like:

```
if (ui.oldPanel.selector == '#Tab1') {
    // The user just left Tab1
}
```

So within that handler you'd perform whatever task you need to perform when a tab changes.

Answer (score 0):

First each tab could have a reference to each form that must be submitted on tab click.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Tab1" data-form="#f1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab2" data-form="#f2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab3" data-form="#f3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab4" data-form="#f4">Tab4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab5" data-form="#f5">Tab5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab6" data-form="#f6">Tab6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then bind a click event to each tab:

```
$("#Main").on("click", "a", function() {
   var formId = $(this).data("form");
   $(formId).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, asign an id attribute to each `<a>` and `<form>` and then do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tab1').click(function(){
         $('#form1').submit();
    });
    $('#tab2').click(function(){
         $('#form2').submit();
    });
    $('#tab3').click(function(){
         $('#form3').submit();
    });
});

</script>
```

A fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KeA7F/15/)